# Apache 2.4.1 mod_wsgi configuration

Tags: python, apache

I downloaded mod_wsgi-3.3 code and build it successfully. I have the mod_wsgi.so library successfully created and copied it to Apache modules folder:

```
modules 1158> ldd mod_wsgi.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffffe39e000)
        libpython2.7.so.1.0 => lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00002b55279bd000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002b5527da2000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002b5527fbd000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002b55281c1000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00002b5528445000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b5528648000)
        libssl.so.6 => /lib64/libssl.so.6 (0x00002b552899f000)
        libcrypto.so.6 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.6 (0x00002b5528bec000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000039cc400000)
        libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00002b5528f3d000)
        libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00002b552916b000)
        libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00002b5529401000)
        libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00002b5529603000)
        libz.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00002b5529828000)
        libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00002b5529a3d000)
        libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00002b5529c45000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00002b5529e47000)
        libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00002b552a05d000)
        libsepol.so.1 => /lib64/libsepol.so.1 (0x00002b552a275000)
```

I added the below line in httpd.conf

LoadModule python_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

But still I get the below error:

```
apache/bin/bin 1173> apachectl start
httpd: Syntax error on line 147 of prasad/bin/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `mod_wsgi' in file prasad/bin/modules/mod_wsgi.so: prasad/bin/modules/mod_wsgi.so: undefined symbol: mod_wsgi
```

But

```
appache/bin/bin 1174> nm ../modules/mod_wsgi.so | grep mod_wsgi
apache/bin/bin 1175>
```

Please help?

OK issue is resolved regarding the Load rule. It should be

LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

But on browser side I keep seeing "

```
Waiting for http://<server>:<port>
```

" to which I am running the Apache? Where can I see the Apache logs or why browser is waiting for so long time?

Comment: Try this directory for the logs: /var/log/apache2/

Answer (score 2):

You can't use mod_wsgi 3.3 with Apache 2.4. Get mod_wsgi source code from mod_wsgi 3.X branch of mod_wsgi source code repository.